# Getiing android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException frequently crash

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Already explored others topic with this same exception. In my case I have closed cursor on proper time. Hence getting this exception rare time from this **if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0)**. Please find the below code and need your expert suggestion for this case.

```
List<User> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USERS;

    try (SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase()) {
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                    User item = new User();
                    item.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                    item.setUserPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(1));

                    itemList.add(item);

                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            }

            cursor.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
    }
    return itemList;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing your code to use :-

```
List<User> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USERS;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase()
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
while (cursor.moveToNext) {
    User item = new user();
    item.setId(cursor.getint(0));
    item.setUserPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(1));
    itemList.add(item);
}
csr.close();
return itemList;
```

- The code is in-principle code, it has not been checked, compiled or run and may therefore contain errors.
- It is inadvisable to catch SQLiteExceptions.
- checking a Cursor for null, from any of the SQliteDatabase methods, is futile as a null Cursor will not be returned.
- No need to check the count as all the Cursor move??? methods return false if the move could not be made so the while(your_cursor.moveToNext()) { .... } will correctly loop through all rows.

A Cursor Window allocation error is typically due to enough memory not being available. The most common reason being because images are being stored in the database.

- as storing data is not limited by a Cursor Window (basically a buffer), it is possible to insert an Image into the database but to then not be able to retrieve it.
- The memory required by a Cursor Window is dependant upon the Android version. I believe it can be 1,2 or 4M.
- Any Image over 4M will result in a failure unless non-standard methodologies are utilised. Even then there will likely be a noticeable impact.
- Expect potential issues for any images 1M or greater.
- If images are up to 100-200k it may be beneficial to store them (even still that's only between 10-5 max per Cursor Window)
- It is suggested to store the image as a file and store the path to the image in the database.

If the above changes result in a failure then (or even before running the above). I would suggest changing the query to only return the columns needed (the id and the phoneNumber). So instead of

```
SELECT * FROM ....
```

- .... is not coded as is, it represents the rest of the original code.

Use (column names made up as they are not revealed in the question, so you will need to substitute the actual column names)

```
SELECT id_column_name, phoneNumber_column_name FROM ....
```

This will reduce the amount of memory required per a row. A Cursor Window MUST be able to hold the minimum of 1 row.

***The stack-trace would have contained more about the error such as the size needed and the available size. If the above does not help, then please edit your question to include the stack trace. You may wish to refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/***

**Additional**

Another potential problem is having too many Cursors open. The maximum number is around 1000. Each Cursor is underneath it all a file and the limitation here is the number of files (file handles) that can be open at once (as such other open files has an impact on the maximum number of open Cursors). As such you should always close Cursors when done with them (which from an Answer you gave you appear to be aware off). In your code an empty Cursor will never be closed which could have the potential to lead to too many being open. The code I have shown will only not close the Cursor if the App crashes, in which case the open Cursors will be closed. Again using the suggested code always closes the Cursor, so adopting this or code based upon the suggestion could eradicate this issue happening.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. I'm restructuring my function as advised. In actual code I'm fetching all data for users in storing the same in user model as all column are required. In my app SQLite database, here only storing text and numbers only. But, for some users this query returns 1300 rows. then only I got this scenario. that memory exceeded 4MB. I'm also trying to reproduce the same.